# how do you match a literal * and a literal + character with vimscript match()?

Tags: vim

Specifically, I'll like to detect lines that have a '+' character in either the first column, or in the second position right after a '*' character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This pattern ?

```
/^\*\=+
```

- `^` matches the start of line
- `\*` matches the star character
- `\=` says *if any*
- `+` matches the ... plus.